# Jquery Tabs UI / div id that is generated

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm currently having issues with the way jquery Tabs UI generate the divs for the tabs.

Normally, the user first would call $("tabs").tab() to initialize the tabs.

```
 <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="controls/form_unassigned.html" id="channel1_link">CH1 N/A</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="controls/form_srw.html" id="channel2_link">CH2 N/A</a>
      </li>

     </ul>
  </div>
```

This will create

```
<div id="ui-tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
</div>

<div id="ui-tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
</div>
```

Which is what is expected where it the div id is "ui-" +  + .

However if you call $("tabs").tab() to initialize again without refreshing the browser the incremented id doesn't start from 0 by starts from 2.  So the tabs will be set to:

```
<div id="ui-tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
</div>

<div id="ui-tabs-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
</div>
```

However, the desire effect I want is for the id to start at 0 every time the initialize is called.  So instead of 3/4 for the div id, i want 1/2.  I tried calling .tabs('destroy') in the beginning of each initialize hoping to that would reset the auto generated id, but that doesn't work either.  I can't find anything on the jquery tabs UI to resolve this issue or maybe i'm just not seeing it.

The reason I want the id to start at 0, is because I use this specific div to populate the content dynamically.

Any advice appreciated, Thanks!
D

Comment: Actually I just figured out the answer.

"Note that if you wish to reuse an existing container, you could do so by matching a title attribute and the container's id:

...

and a container like:
...

(Note how white space is replaced with an underscore)

This is useful if you want a human readable hash in the URL instead of a cryptic generated one. "

So you can just use the title to assign it a div id.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without modifying the jQuery UI sourcecode.

`tabId` is only visible from inside the [anonymous function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js#L14) wrapping the tabs module and it doesn't "export" any functions to change it.

If a very dirty hack is acceptable for you, add the following inside the function:

```
window.resetTabID = function() {
    tabId = 0;
}
```

This would allow you to call the global function `resetTabID()` to reset the tab id. However, you better don't use hacks like that.

Comment: assign a title to specify the div id.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this post](https://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.4/docs/tabs.html#Ajax_mode) - use the title attribute.

```html
<div id="example">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="ahah_1.html"><span>Content 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ahah_2.html"><span>Content 2</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ahah_3.html"><span>Content 3</span></a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
Obviously this degrades gracefully - the links, e.g. the content, will still be accessible with JavaScript disabled.

Note that if you wish to reuse an existing container, you could do so by matching a title attribute and the container's id:

<li><a href="hello/world.html" title="Todo Overview"> ... </a></li>
and a container like:

<div id="Todo_Overview"> ... </div>
```

Works great!